# Restricted collecting data on GA4

Tags: dataframe, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Why am I restricted to 10,000 rows when i collect data on one property on GA4 ? When the date range is too big I have to reduce it to manage this issue. Is there a parameter to change or a solution to this problem ?
Here is my code, where can I manage the page token parameter ?

```
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()

    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name=dim) for dim in dimensions],
        metrics=[Metric(name=m) for m in metrics],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=str(start_date), end_date=str(end_date))],
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)

    output = {}
    headers = [header.name for header in response.dimension_headers] + [
        header.name for header in response.metric_headers
    ]
    rows = []
    for row in response.rows:
        rows.append(
            [dimension_value.value for dimension_value in row.dimension_values]
            + [metric_value.value for metric_value in row.metric_values]
        )

    output["headers"] = headers
    output["rows"] = rows
    analytics_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=output["headers"], data=output["rows"])
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google analytics api has a max page limit of 10,000 rows to request additional rows you just need to use the next page token and page over the requests.

How this is done depends upon the language you are using.

Comment: I'm currently using Python, I m trying to add all data in a dataframe but I can't if I have multiple pages ?

Comment: You could if you buffered all the data first then showed it to the user.   Are you using the reporting api or the data api?   I may have a sample laying around.

Comment: I am making an API request, so I guess I'm using the data api